# Knex: How to trim the result?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, knex.js

When using SQL, the query can be written as:

```
select RTRIM(dept_id) as dept_id from dept
```

Apart from using `knex.raw`, could we achieve trimming using `knex` native API?

My SQL Server version is 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use knex.raw() as partial query as below instead of changing the whole query in knex.raw()

```
knex.select("*", knex.raw(RTrim(dept_id) as dept_id)).from("dept")
```

Answer (score 0):

For trimming properly you have to do both LTRIM, RTRIM. I would suggest you to do the trimming at the DB layer. Instead of bringing data to the middle tier and trimming over there. When you trim at DB layer, you are also reducing the amount of data travel to the other layers.

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(dept_id)) as dept_id from dept
```

Comment: I know how to do it in raw sql. I could simply achieve my expected result by using  `knex.raw('select LTRIM(RTRIM(dept_id)) as dept_id from dept')`. But I want to know if there are any knex native syntax could support trimming. for example : `knex.trim()`

I tried to do `knex.select(LTRIM(RTRIM(dept_id)) as dept_id).from('dept')`, but it didnt work out.